# How to simultaneously set null values to specific value in many columns?

Tags: sql, ms-access, null, sql-update, ms-access-2010

The goal I`m trying to achive is to update value  based on value on another table, the problem is that I have to join on multible colunms. Just look it:

```
update excel_attributes
inner join info_columns on 
(excel_attributes.source = info_columns.source) and 
(excel_attributes.r010_table = info_columns.tableName) and  
(excel_attributes.r010_comment = info_columns.comment) and 
(excel_attributes.r010_column = info_columns.columnName) and  
(excel_attributes.r010_type = info_columns.Datatype)  

set excel_attributes.source_id = info_columns.info_columns_id;
```

There are twice more columns. Obviouly `left join` wont help, to many cases(*2^numOfCol*).

This is why I want to set that value to be equal not null to be able to perform `inner join`.

Doing this way is possible, but boring:

```
update excel_attributes
set col = ""
where isnull(col );
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation, that you need to perform such weird update is not normal. But `iif` fucnction can be used. Analogs for other DBMS are [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp).

So the solution is written below:

```
update excel_attributes
inner join info_columns on
(iif(isnull(excel_attributes.source), "", excel_attributes.source) = iif(isnull(info_columns.source), "", info_columns.source)) and 
(iif(isnull(excel_attributes.r010_table), "", excel_attributes.r010_table) = iif(isnull(info_columns.tableName), "", info_columns.tableName)) and 
(iif(isnull(excel_attributes.r010_comment), "", excel_attributes.r010_comment) = iif(isnull(info_columns.comment), "", info_columns.comment)) and 
(iif(isnull(excel_attributes.r010_column), "", excel_attributes.r010_column) = iif(isnull(info_columns.columnName), "", info_columns.columnName)) and 
(iif(isnull(excel_attributes.r010_type), "", excel_attributes.r010_type) = iif(isnull(info_columns.Datatype), "", info_columns.Datatype)) 

set excel_attributes.source_id = info_columns.info_columns_id;
```